# Trying to get a value from a column right to my selected cell (as the values are coorelated)

Tags: vba, excel, range

I'm trying to run through cells in a range (which works fine as I use it in a different macro as well), but now I also need the value at the right of it to use this value in my calculations, however it seems to not run through it as intended. Any help or advice is welcome, I'm pretty novice at coding.

```
For Each cell In rng
    currentChimneyHeight = cell.Value
    currentChimneyDiameter = cell(cell.Row, cell.Column + 1).Value
    Worksheets("Stab-klasse").Range("C27") = currentChimneyDiameter
    Worksheets("Stab-klasse").Range("C26") = currentChimneyHeight
    Worksheets("Dosis en depositie").Range("B7:B28").Copy
    Worksheets("Variatie Schouw").Range(Cells(7, currentCollumn), Cells(28, currentCollumn)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Worksheets("Dosis en depositie").Range("E7:E28").Copy
    Worksheets("Variatie Schouw").Range(Cells(7, currentCollumn + 1), Cells(28, currentCollumn + 1)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Cells(6, currentCollumn) = currentChimneyHeight
    Cells(6, currentCollumn + 1) = currentChimneyDiameter
    currentCollumn = currentCollumn + 2
Next cell
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> currentChimneyDiameter = cell(cell.Row, cell.Column + 1).Value
> ```

This will not get you the next cell, but a cell that is *very far away* from your `cell`. If will `offset` your `cell` by `(cell.Row, cell.Column + 1)`. To get just the next cell, use instead of the above:

```
currentChimneyDiameter = cell.offset(0 ,1).Value2
'                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I was completely oblivious to the offset command. Fixed it by using that command now, however still using .Value as it is not intented to add up values, but only use both of them in a different calculation. Many thanks!

Comment: @WouterSlechten `.value2` is exactly like `.value` unless the value is a date or a currency. It is only a matter of good practice to prefer `.Value2` for fetching from Excel to VBA.